# What do we mean by the term "Number of things"?

Tags: untagged

I am reading the book ["The Number-System of Algebra (2nd edition)."](https://archive.org/stream/thenumbersystemo17920gut/17920-pdf#page/n11/mode/2up)   I have some problems with the the first article: "Number".

The author has confined the concept of *number of things* to the groups which have all distinct elements, that is the number of letters in a group having elements A,B,C is $3$ *iff* $A,B,C$ all are distinct.

> - What is the definition and explanation, that is what is the meaning of the term *number of things* in general English.
> - Why Professor Fine has confined  this term only for those groups which have all the distinct things.
> - How the modern Mathematics defines the term *Number of things$^{2}$*.

---

<sup>My personal understanding is as:</sup>

"Thing" refers to both "abstract object" and "concrete object". The "group" of Fine's book is not the "Set" of our modern language. When I say I have 3 coins in my pocket I mean that I have three different "concrete objects" in my pocket. I understand that in real life we do count multiple "abstract objects" of same type as a single one. I am still doubtful on my understanding.
It  appears to me that the modern mathematics does not explain the term *Number of things* when the things under consideration are concrete objects. Read my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732370/what-do-we-mean-by-the-term-number-of-things?noredirect=1#comment1551968_732370) for my confused mind. I do not have enough knowledge of modern math(especially set theory). There might be some explanation of the term *Number of things* given by the modern set theory.

---

${}^2$ Things may refer to both "abstract objects" and "concrete objects".